# Triggering actions in Android smartphone via Bluetooth from Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-micro, android

Am working on a wearable using Arduino Micro and I am thinking it would be cool if I can trigger some events in my smartphone using Arduino. Say for example a button press in my wearable should trigger events like opening music player, reducing/increasing volume or opening some Android Apps.

Sorry for providing just a rough view of the idea. So I want to know to perform similar actions listed above, Do I need to create a Android app for it? I don't find any readymade app that fits my requirement. Or Is there any feasible way to achieve what I need without having to break my head with Android developing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Been there, done that. You **have** to learn how to program Android. And keep your development environment updated (zillion of MB each time). And Android is ... peculiar ... you rotate your phone and your app restart. And Google change things every other weeks. Things like that. Arduino is stable.

Comment: So it's going to be one tough road isn't it? Any advice on where to get started or which IDE I should choose. Any tips ? :-P

Comment: Here is where I learnt Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/.

Comment: For the volume there are standard Media Control bluetooth commands. The simplest way of doing those may be to hack wires into a cheap Media Keys BLE device ($5 or so on eBay).

Comment: @Majenko Any link to those commands ?